# How to select the previous selected tab in mat-tab in angular 8

Tags: angular

There are List of data, when user click on first row then shown details with many tabs, always show the tab "ProductInformation" as selected by default.
If the user selects another row in the list, always remember and show the last selected tab of the last list item
Exception: if the newly selected item do not have the same tab, which was last shown in the last item, switch to the first tab

Below is same code which I tried to do, but its work fine as "the switch to the previously selected tab is done after the details view is reloaded", but Target behavior: load the tab by selected initially (without switching it afterwards.

Please let me know how I can do as per target behavior.

in html:

```
<mat-tab-group class="tab-group" #tabGroup (focusChange)="tabChanged($event)" [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTabIndex">
    <mat-tab label="ProductInformation">
      <div class="tab-content">
        ...........
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="StocksInformation">
      <div class="tab-content">
        ...........
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="SpareInformation">
      <div class="tab-content">
        ...........
      </div>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

in ts file:

```
selectedTabIndex: number = 0;
@ViewChild('tabGroup', null) private tabGroup: MatTabGroup;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selectedTabIndex = this.utils.activeTabSession("activeTabDetail", this.tabGroup, this.selectedTabIndex);
    });
  }


activeTabSession(sessionKeyName: string, tabGroup: MatTabGroup, selectedTabIndex: number): number {
    var activeTabDetail = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(sessionKeyName));
    if (activeTabDetail != null && activeTabDetail != undefined) {
      selectedTabIndex = 0;
      tabGroup._tabs.forEach(element => {
        if (element.textLabel == activeTabDetail.tabName) {
          selectedTabIndex = element.position;
        }
      });
      if(selectedTabIndex == 0) {
        var tabDetails = {tabIndex: tabGroup._tabs.first.position, tabName: '' + tabGroup._tabs.first.textLabel + ''};
        sessionStorage.setItem(sessionKeyName, JSON.stringify(tabDetails));
      }
    }
    return selectedTabIndex;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the property

```
selectedTabIndex: number = 0;
```

Every property can also be written as a combination of get and set.

```
private _selectedTabIndex: number = 0;
get selectedTabIndex() {
  return this._selectedTabIndex;
}
set selectedTabIndex(value: number) {
  this._selectedTabIndex = value;
}
```

You can extend the alternative variant very easily by a second property, which does not expose a set.

```
private _selectedTabIndex: number = 0;
private _previousSelectedTabIndex: number = 0;
get selectedTabIndex() {
  return this._selectedTabIndex;
}
set selectedTabIndex(value: number) {
  this._previousSelectedTabIndex = this._selectedTabIndex;
  this._selectedTabIndex = value;
}
get previousSelectedTabIndex() {
  return this._previousSelectedTabIndex;
}
```

When requesting a tab change to the previous you can just use the `_previousSelectedTabIndex` property by saying `this.selectedTabIndex = this._previousSelectedTabIndex`.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually for every listed row's, tabs will changes (tab position) according to the backend data. Hence I'm using the tab name to find out the location (as you see in my code snippet). Could you please elaborate lit bit on this using tab name instead of tab index.  Hope your code covers the _Target behavior_: **Load the tab by selected initially (without switching it afterwards)**

Answer (score 0):

You can store the info in the browser.

```
handleMatTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
        localStorage.setItem('userTabLocation', event.index);
    }
```

On page load, get the info from local storage and set the tab.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let index = localStorage.getItem('userTabLocation') || 0;     this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = index; 
}
```